# Determine Type of Object in Linked List

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a linked list which stores objects for "Car":

```
LinkedList<Car> cars = new LinkedList<Car>();
```

A car can be either large or small, and as such, these are split into 2 subclasses (LargeCar, SmallCar).

I need to iterate through my linked list and count the number of SmallCar objects.

How can this be done?

Comment: either use `instanceof` or add some method to base `Car` class which will return is it large or small

Answer (score 2):

```
int small = 0;
int large = 0;
for (Car nextCar : cars) {
    if (nextCar instanceof LargeCar) {
       large++;
    } else if (nextCar instanceof SmallCar) {
       small++;
    }
}
```

Written free hand so may have the odd typo.

Experiment here: [code](https://ideone.com/Otc3N1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupingBy:

```
        LinkedList<Car> cars = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new LargeCar(),new LargeCar(),new LargeCar(),new LargeCar(),
                new LargeCar(),new SmallCar(),new SmallCar(),new SmallCar()
        ));

        Map<Class, Long> counted =
                cars.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getClass, Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(counted.get(LargeCar.class));
        System.out.println(counted.get(SmallCar.class));
```